# UnsupportedClassVersionError when starting a Tomcat server

Tags: tomcat

When I try to start my Tomcat server am getting the below error; can anyone help me out?

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin>tomcat
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version n
umber in .class file
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access+100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader+1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
```

Failed to run service as console application

Comment: Seems like a mismatch of versions. What java version are you using?

Comment: Make sure you have latest JDK, and JAVA_HOME env variable is pointing to it.   The error is seen typically when your class is compiled using later version of JDK

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat 7 requires at least java `1.6`, see [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html).

To check which java version you have you can run

```
java -version
```

in a command prompt or just go to

```
Control panel > Programs > java
```

then in the `General` tab click on `about`.

Make sure you have installed java `1.6` or higher and correctly setup the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

If you don't want to install a newer java version then you can download an lower version of Tomcat which runs with the java version you have actually. But I will **not recommend** that, better install a newer version of java.